# Can I build a Dashboard in Sharepoint Online?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online, dashboard-designer-2013

I would like to create a dashboard in Sharepoint Online http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-online-online-collaboration-software-FX103789366.aspx.

I have seen references to a Dashboard Designer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806339.aspx, but have not found a way to install it. I think it might be available from a link in the on-premise SharePoint online.

I also installed the "Office Developer Tools for VisualStudio 2012". When I try to create a "SharePoint 2013 - Visual Web Part", it says "The required version of SharePoint Foundation 2013 ... is not installed on this system". This leads me to think I have to install VisualStudio on our server, which I can't do (SharePoint is online).

I would like my dashboard to retrieve data from an external data source (an Azure database), so I don't just want to publish a spreadsheet. I've already created an external list to retrieve the data, I now want to put it into a webpart.

Is it possible to build Dashboards in SharePoint online?

Comment: Cross site publishing isn't allowed. This question was originally posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505703/can-i-build-a-dashboard-in-sharepoint-online

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data in a list then you can create dashboards using XSLT which can be used in O365.  There is a post on how to do this on my blog http://paylord.wordpress.com.

Comment: Dave, one more question.  Do you know if there are limitations on the Dashboard tools, etc. in O365?

Comment: As far as I know what was the PerformancePoint element of SharePoint is not available in O365.